# When I refresh browser then the NAVIGATION bar change the place. Why?

Tags: html, css

When I refresh browser then the NAVIGATION bar changes place. 
Why is this happening? Where is the error?

I cannot detect the problem. I think, I have written many extra CSS style. Is it? Please help to fix this.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="con_header">
            <h1> SITE NAME</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="chosen"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    background-color: #202628;
    height: 80px;
    color: #e7e7e7;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.con_header{
    width:1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.con_header h1{
    float: left;
}
.con_header nav{
    float: right;
}
.con_header::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}

.con_header ul{
    margin-top:26px;
}
.con_header li{
    display: inline;

}
.con_header li a{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 33px 10px 33px 10px;
    margin: -4px;
}
.con_header li a:hover{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #e84c3d;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 33px 10px 33px 10px;
    margin: -4px;
}
.chosen{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #e84c3d;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 33px 15px 33px 15px;
    margin: -4px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jo45sdob/

Comment: What browser did you get this strange behaviour? I could not reproduce yours in Chrome.

Comment: All browsers are showing different strange behavior

Comment: try load the style before html? I am not sure, just a thought.

Comment: I change the width to fit the fiddle but I don't see a problem if the css is load before <body> http://jsfiddle.net/hsvwo9wp/

Comment: I cannot check the jsfiddle because it is down right now

Comment: Refresh The browser to Understand the promblem , I want the LOGO + Navigation bar in the middle with Width: 1170px

Answer (score 0):

try commenting out the space between the li tags like this:

```
<ul>
                <li class="chosen"><a href="">HOME</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="">CONTACTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

thats if I understood what the problem was..

Comment: please check this in the chorm then will see problem